# How to insert row to child table with null value of column that is foreign key

Tags: php, html, sql, arrays, class

**Two Table**

First table  CUST_ENTRY

```
cust_id(primary key),cust_name,cust_add
```

Second table  CUST_PRICE

```
cust_price_id,cust_id(foreign key),cust_price1,cust_date1,cust_price2,cust_date2
```

I have insert first table completely but  second table data cust_price2 and cust_date2 is insert  blank but that not possible.

Please help me.

Comment: Show us the schema for these 2 tables, I mean a complete schema, not a summary

Comment: what did you try?